# Datatable: when using 3000 records my datatable is getting loading slowly, and when click on buttton on change action not responding immediately

Tags: datatables

When I click on search button, my page getting freeze, alerts & masking are not working but when page loads completing alerts are popup.

Pleas help me on this

1. I have 3000 rows in a Datatable:
2. I Have two radio buttons

- Show only Difference
- All

When I click any one of button **applyFitler** function will get execute and **executeFilter** is filter function that executes when table is getting Draw,

3. What I expected is, when I click on any of Radio button, Mask with **Please wait** should show immediately, but it shows before one second (9th second) of returning results to Datatable. Total its taking 10 seconds to apply filter and return Datatable.
4. During these 10 seconds by browser page getting freeze

```
    var applyFitler = function() {
            alertBlock('Please wait..');
            // clear the global search box
            __DATATABLE.search('');
            // set columnIndex to match data attribute of each column (used in our custom search while allowing moving of columns)
            $('#devresult th').each(function(index) {
                var headerText = $(this).data('col-header');
                __TABLEHEADERS[headerText].columnIndex = $(this).data('column-index');
            });
            if (__DATATABLE != undefined) {
                __DATATABLE.draw();
            }
    
            alertUnblock();
    };

    var executeFilter = function(settings, data, dataIndex, rowData, counter) {
            var rows = __DATATABLE.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
            var showRow= $("input[name=showRow]:checked").val();
            if(showRow == "notshow") {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you give more details ? Sample of data? In which context?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have not already done so, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In this case, it will be difficult to help you unless you [edit] your question to provide more details. Ideally, this would take the form of a [mre].

Comment: @YLR, Updated with more info I hope this helps you to understand

Thanks

Comment: @andrewjames , Updated with more info, I hope this helps you to understand. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the updates, but they do not really help (apart from the fact that I now see you have 3,000 records, not 300). I have no way to recreate your problem, based on the information in the question.

Comment: @andrewjames, from the above code of line alertBlock('Please wait..'); (this is a mask) not working when using filters. 

Ex:- If I apply filters >  
1. immediately it should say PLEASE WAIT.. Mask, but not working 
2. its taking 10 sec to load data based on filters
3. mask is applying 10th sec and disappearing

I should expect mask should apply at step 1 and disappear after filter results loaded (step 3) . this is a happening due to datatable filter function is used

Comment: Thank you, again, for the update - but your comment basically repeats information which is already in the question.